# Speed up RAID 1 drive read speeds

Tags: raid, raid1, windows-sbs-2011

Sorry I don't know much about this stuff...we have been having issues with a slow server, very slow for users and when you access the server direct, we have added more RAM but it seems it may be a drive speed issue.

It is a SBS 2011 with RAID 1. The HDD is running close to 100% continuously and has a Queue length of 30-50.

What would be the best way to improve this?

Below is a screen shot of our resource monitor.

[image: Resource Monitor]

RAM Resource
[image: RAM Resource]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Replace with faster disk?  SSDs would be really fast.

Answer (score 4):

All fingers point at SQL Server, which is doing a lot of reads.  It would seem that your disk literally can't satisfy the demand for data.

Assuming you are using RAID 1 (plain old mirroring) as opposed to RAID 0+1 (striping and mirroring), I'd suggest that you add an additional array and associated logical drive.  Then move your SQL Server .MDB and .LDF files to this array.  In a purists' world, you'd separate your MDBs (database files) from your LDFs (transaction logs) and your TempDB (temporary table space for sorts, re-indexing, Etc)., but that may be overkill.

Additionally, adding even more RAM will allow SQL Server to keep more data in memory, causing less disk I/O.  This may be worthwhile anyway, as your server is doing a lot of pagefile reads as well.

You don't mention what type of server (hardware) you're using, and whether you're talking about hardware RAID or software RAID...

Finally, you may want to ask why SQL Server is doing so many reads.  This'll require a Database Administrator.  For example, is there a duff query causing full-table scans, do you need to add further indexes, Etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will get back to you regarding hardware or software RAID. I thought it might be SQL causing the issues as they use the server for exchange, BCM and sharepoint. Although I have no idea how to setup what you suggest I will look into it.

Comment: Wow.  Hadn't spotted Exchange on there too!  Looking even closer, it looks like it's running WSUS as well.  Perhaps time for a bit of architecture reconsideration?  However, this is just me not used to running SBS; I'm guessing that's the idea of it!  Can you post your physical RAM figure, plus your total commit charge?

Comment: I've edited the question and added a screen shot of the memory info. From what i understand store.exe will use up whatever RAM is left over so will always show around 100% usage?

Comment: Yes SBS is meant to run all this on it, they had a server with SBS 2003 on it for years with only 2GB RAM and a poor spec and even that didn't run this slow! We've recently upgraded to SBS 2011 and got a new server.

Comment: I'd say you definitely need more RAM, even before you consider looking at your RAID set.  Your physical RAM utilisation is very near 100%, meaning requests for additional memory can only be serviced once the working set of other processes has been trimmed, and pushed into paged memory (i.e.: after disk I/O).  The same goes for hard-page faults, that is, more disk I/O for page-in operations.  Basically, get more RAM, then re-check your disk I/O.   And yes, MS Exch likes to consume RAM (by design), but so does SQL Server (again by design).  SQL Server can be tuned (capped).  More RAM please ;-)